# Easy question on the integral of a linear equation B)

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the following image.
[image]

My concern is with question B. I input $-3t^2/10$, but the system returns false. Am I missing something? Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue line in the included image is given by the equation $f(t) = -\frac{3}{5}t + 3$. An antiderivative of $f$ is then given by

\begin{align}
\int f(t) \, \mathrm{d} t &= \int \left(-\frac{3}{5}t + 3\right) \, \mathrm{d} t \\
 &= -\frac{3}{10}t^2 + 3t + C
\end{align}
Taking the constant term $C$ to be zero gives

$$
F(t) = -\frac{3}{10}t^2 + 3t
$$